# using aws credentials manager for aws rds database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I have a general question for the rds feature within aws credentials manager. When I get the secret, it looks like this:

[image]

Does this mean that these credentials directly will work or is the password encrypted? Like if I wanted to sign into my database with a connection what credentials do I use and do these credentials auto rotate with the cycling feature?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the **RDSDataClient** to access a database such as a Serverless Amazon Aurora instance.

To successfully connect to the database using the **RdsDataClient** object, you must setup an AWS Secrets Manager secret that is used for authentication. For information, see [Rotate Amazon RDS database credentials automatically with AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/).

To see an AWS tutorial that shows this concept and the corresponding code, see this example that uses the AWS SDK for Kotlin. You will need these values to make a successful connection:

```
  private val secretArnVal = "<Enter the secret manager ARN>"
  private val resourceArnVal =  "<Enter the database ARN>" ;
```

See the full example here:

[Creating the Serverless Amazon Aurora item tracker application using the Kotlin RdsDataClient API](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/usecases/serverless_rds)

I just tested this again (been a while since it was developed), and it works perfectly.

[image]

We will port this example to use other supported programming languages too - like AWS SDK for Java.

**UPDATE**

You **only need to use Secret Manager** when using the **RDSDataClient**.  As mentioned in that tutorial, the **RdsDataClient** object is only supported for an **Aurora Serverless DB cluster** or an **Aurora PostgreSQL**. If you are using MySQL RDS, you cannot use the the **RdsDataClient** object. You would use a supported JDBC API.

Comment: Yes @smac2020 I set this up but when I am getting connection errors to my database when I input the values retrieved from get secret value. In the screenshot above, the console provides me with credentials which does not work in dbbeaver or other mysql apps.

Comment: See update comments. If you are using MySQL, then you cannot use the RDSDataClient.